# [Robot Framework][RIDE]error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm using RIDE to connect to a remote server and execute a command, I have written the following code:

```
    *** Settings ***
Library           SSHLibrary

*** Variables ***
${HOST}           servername
${USERNAME}       username
${PASSWORD}       password

*** Test Cases ***
Remote
    ${index}=    Open Connection    ${HOST}
    Log Many    ${index}
    ${output}=    Login    ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
    Log Many    ${output}
```

I disabled firewall and run RIDE as administrator , but still have the error :
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Any help with the case?

Thank you

Comment: please add the code and see if the port your using is available

Comment: I added the code , I don't know what is the port number to use , how can I get its value

Comment: The target machine seems to be not listening on the whatever port you are trying to connect! Make sure that the port is open on the target machine/server.

Comment: This almost certainly has nothing to do with RIDE. To eliminate that as a possibility, have you run this test outside of RIDE (ie: from a command line)?

Comment: is the target machine setup to allow remote connections?

Comment: how you solve it?

Comment: I've been bothering with this error, although it seldom happens. I can confirm that this has nothing to do with RIDE. Once this happens, the rest test cases would fail.